# High poly mesh too high

Tags: mesh

I'm new to blender so I'm very confused and don't really have a work flow yet. I blindly sculpted a model and now the poly's are too high to texture paint or vertex paint it. I know I have to like retopologize it or UV unwrapp it, but I'm super new at this and am just confused on what to do next and how to go about it. Could anyone give me some insight on the steps I should be taking after building a high poly mesh and not wanting to lose detail? (3,314,926 verts) Thanks!!!

Comment: Hello :). I don't sculpt, but Blender has some rather powerful remeshing tools. Might be worth looking into...

Comment: What kind of model is it? Humanoid? A common workflow is to sculpt a high poly version, then do retopo or reshape a low-poly base mesh to create a low-poly version, (optional: add multres modifier and add more details), finally bake the normal map to get the details on the low-poly model. Have a look at the [sculpting an old man in blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6nEBobSaLk&list=PLn3ukorJv4vu9Tkxju13cHYZCR9kIloe2&index=1) series.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the "Decimate" modifier.
It will try to reduce the number of poly but keeping the global geometry of your mesh.

You can also search for some retopology workflow, or some addon.
And last, you can try to use some other tool for Blender like Instant Mesh
https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Blender 4.0, there are some methods for decreasing your poly-count.

1. When you get to the Sculpting menu, go to 'Remesh'. If you remesh at a low amount, then your model will increase in polys. But at a higher amount, the polys will decrease.
   [image: Option 1]
2. Repeat the steps above, but when you've remeshed (make sure Fix Poles is enabled for this method!), go into the Data menu on the right and open the Remesh menu there. Make sure Quad Mode is picked and you can freely tweak the parameters once opened.
   [image: Option 2]
3. As mentioned by B.Pader, you can use addons and help make your retoplogy easier.

Although, here's some advice that I believe will bode well with you in the future. Quads are your best friend in modelling, especially if low-poly and high-poly workflows are established in your pipeline. I believe Option 2 is a very ideal method of retoplogy in my opinion.

Wishing you the best of luck on your journey!